# RadScheduleView: force the schedule item to show all of the title in Edit mode, instead of clipping it

Tags: telerik, radscheduleview

RadScheduleView: force the schedule item to show all of the title in edit mode, instead of clipping it.

in Edit mode the items label turns to "This is my na..."

I need it to display the entire label ("This is my name"). In other words auto-size to whatever the text is.

Bazzy

Answer (score 0):

MinAppointmentWidth="250"
There doesn't seems to be an auto-expand" option, just an option to set the minimum width of the appointment item. It will have to do.